# Hibernate, n+1 queries when i delete an entity in a @OneToMany relation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I want to define a bidirectional @OneToMany relation. I did it the following way:

```
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JsonIgnore
  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  private List<CustomerEmployeeRole> roles;

  // more fields
}

public class CustomerEmployeeRole {

  @ManyToOne
  @NotNull
  private Customer customer;

 // more fields
}
```

Everything works as expected, the only problem is that n+1 queries are executed when i delete a customer. n is the number of roles the customer has. For every role the following query is executed:

```
delete from customer_employee_role where id=?
```

It would be possible to delete all roles in one query:

```
delete from customer_employee_role where customer_id=?
```

I assume hibernate does n+1 queries because of `mappedBy = "customer"`. I want to keep the annotation, because i want to avoid a join table. Is there any way to tell hibernate to only execute one query instead of n queries in this case? Otherwise i would have to write my own queries which would work too, but it´s not really elegant.

Comment: Out of curiosity what SQL is generated if you call customer.roles.clear(); merge(customer); repostory.delete(customer) ? I'm reasonably certain that the way you've got it mapped now there's not anyway around the behavior you're seeing, and as you pointed out in the other comments you'd have to use custom code to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The `n+1` queries are because of the `CascadeType.ALL`. Since you set this attribute, the CustomerEmployeeRole's are deleted too. So if you want to remove a Customer let's see what happens assuming that the customer have 2 roles :

1)  delete from CustomerEmployeeRole where id = ..

2)  delete from CustomerEmployeeRole where id = ..

**3)  delete from Customer where id = ..**    here is your `+1` query.

**P.S.:** In case you have any more questions about which is the best way to map a `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`, `@OneToOne` or what is happening behind the scenes [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) is a good tutorial. ( Same for the other annotations )

Comment: Yes, i know that. I want to delete all `CustomerEmployeeRoles` when the customer is deleted. But like i stated in the post, instead of queries 1) and 2) being executed the following query could just be executed and delete all of the customers roles: `delete from customer_employee_role where customer_id = ..`.That would just be one query and that would do the same job as the n queries.

Comment: In this case, you're deleting the roles **only**. You have to delete the customer too. There is no other solution to get to the `n` number of queries.

Comment: Yes, that happens afterwards. Like i said, that query replaces the n queries, the one query deleting the customer still happens after. So there are 2 queries in total instead of n+1 queries which is obviosuly way better. But the only way i can currently achieve this is by writing the query on my own. I would like hibernate to automatically use it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're referring to.

Comment: Currently i would have to do `customerRepository.deleteAllCustomerRolesFromCustomer(customer)` and `customerRepository.delete(customer)`. The first query is the specified custom query above. That way theres only 2 queries in total. I would like to have this behaviour by just calling `customerReposiotry.delete(customer)` without having to write and execute the custom query beforehand.

Comment: I suggest you to think about this delete as a transactional operation. What happens if you say `delete from customer_employee_role where customer_id = .. ` and it fails for the 3rd row? then it automatically rollback, but what I want to point out is that this delete behind the scenes does the same amount of operations like two `delete from .. where id = `

Comment: My main problem is/was that having that many queries results in a lot of requests to the database. With a ping between the server my API is running on and the database, having n+1 queries would lead to some performance issues because of the ping for each request. But i guess i could use batching to group up the delete queries and send them in one batch/request.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think about that, but the batch could be a solution to this problem. :)